# How to show this equality?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I need some help for showing the following equality $$\displaystyle \left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^m=\sum_{|\alpha|=m}\frac{m!}{\alpha!}x^\alpha$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$. Here $\alpha\in\mathbb N^n$ is a multi-index. The proof is done using induction on the multi-index length. I've already spent several hours on it but I wasn't able to finish the proof..

Comment: This is the [Multinomial Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) A proof is given in the article.

Comment: Note that the sum over $|\alpha| = m+1$ is an outer sum over $|\alpha| = m$ and an inner sum over the other element of $\alpha$. This can be a basis for a proof by induction.

Comment: thanks guys I'll take a looked at the article..

Comment: well for a multi-index of length one it is easy then I wrote a multi-index $\alpha$ of length $n+1$ as $\alpha=\beta+e_j$ for some multi-index $\beta$ of length $n$ and some index $j\in \{1, \ldots, n\}$. Then I think I can write $$\displaystyle\sum_{|\alpha|=m+1}\frac{(m+1)!}{\alpha!}x^\alpha=\sum_{|\beta|=m}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(m+1)!}{(\beta_j+1)\beta!}x^\alpha x_j,$$ is that right?

Comment: Well in the article the induction is done on the number of terms in the left hand sum, I was trying to use induction on the multi-index length, now I'm confused..

Comment: How this question relate to PDE?

Comment: @doraemonpaul this question appear in the context of pseudodifferential operators which is a theory highly applicable in PDE..For example, using the above equality with a slight modification I can prove the following result: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447635/prove-varphi-in-mathcals-mathbb-rn-if-and-only-if-the-following-inequali . I'm still writing that proof..

Comment: But don't you feel odd as you ask a question about series but does not contain any series-type tags?

Answer (score 1):

This is the multinomial theorem. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) for a proof by induction.